# Naming variables from other variables

Tags: variable-definitions

I'm inside a Do loop and I'm constructing a Dataset. I have consumers that come each period and I need a unique identifier for each of the consumer. 
To uniquely identify a consumer I need 3 variables: Bt, p and q.

`Consumers = Dataset[{<|"Id" -> Bt p q, "B" -> Bt, "RC" -> "n"|>}]`

If I put in Id Bt, p, q of course, I get the product of the 3 numbers.

I would like to get a unique identifier from the 3 variables Bt,p,q. If I use multiplication in order to get a unique Id I need to use a prime number. What I would like to do is to name Id with Bt,p,q in that order so that I get a unique identifier without involving primes.

Comment: how about `{Bt, p, q}`? Your identifier will be an unique array.

Comment: Thanks. Would the Query for the identifier be less efficient with an array?

Comment: I don't think so. You can also create a new number by using those three numbers like `ToExpression@StringJoin@Map[ToString, {1, 35, 2}]`